Row Action is not using unique URL for redirection .NET Kentico
I am writing this function to attempt to make each Row element clickable to open a new window with a specific URL designated for each row. I am doing this in Kentico Admin module. In every resource I have looked at and every AI I have asked, this logic should work but it does not.
private Row MapToRow(IContentQueryDataContainer container)
{
    int contentItemID = container.GetValue<int>(nameof(NewsArticle.SystemFields.ContentItemID));
    string newWebID = webIDs[contentItemID.ToString()];
    string url = $"https://localhost:5000/admin/webpages-1/en_{newWebID}/content";

    return new Row
    {
        Cells = new List<Cell>
        {
            new NewsArticleColumn(nameof(NewsArticle.NewsArticleHeadline), container.GetValue<string>(nameof(NewsArticle.NewsArticleHeadline))),
            new NewsArticleColumn(nameof(NewsArticle.NewsArticleCategories), GetCategoryNames(container)),
            new NewsArticleColumn("Author", GetAuthorNames(container)),
            new NewsArticleColumn("Status", GetArticleStatus(container)),
            new NewsArticleColumn(nameof(NewsArticle.NewsArticleDate), container.GetValue<DateTime>(nameof(NewsArticle.NewsArticleDate)).ToShortDateString()),
            new NewsArticleColumn("Scheduled", GetArticlePublishDate(container)),
            new NewsArticleColumn("URL", url)
        },
        Action = new Kentico.Xperience.Admin.Base.Action(ActionType.Link)
        {
            Parameter = url,
            LinkParameters = new LinkParameters
            {
                UseWindowOpen = true,
                Target = "_blank",
                WindowOpenLinkParameters = new WindowOpenLinkParameters
                {
                    Features = "width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

In this function, the url string value is unique for every iteration of MapToRow based on the contentID, as it should be. I know this because the NewsArticleColumn string value for URL column is correct. However, when clicking on a row in the Kentico content page, all rows are redirecting to same URL which is from the first call to MapToRow. So, for the first content item in the table it works as expected, but not for the rest. I am not sure why it is a different value than the URL column since the same variable is being used.
Any help or ideas to look at would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have added logging to ensure all urls are the correct value when running through the function, which they are.
I have tried clearing browser cache.
I have tried adding the column value url as a clickable link rather than having the whole row as a clickable object, but the value is being rendered as plain text and I am not sure where it is being rendered to make it render as HTML.
